# Asp.net MVC 4 Layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, layout

I am fairly new with Asp.net MVC and programming in general. 
I am having an issue with using layout in Asp.Net MVC 4. I have a main layout page. This page has all the jquery and javascript file reference at the bottom above the body close tag, and the css files in the head section below the title. I have another layout, _UserLayout, that use the _Layout file. When I reference the _UserLayout file in view, the scripts are not render. I have to also use script.render on the view. Why didn't the script render when I use the layout?

The regular Layout Page:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization;
@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)

    @RenderSection("style", false)
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 50px;" >

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar fa fa-user fa-3x">tester</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">About us</a>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Login","Account")">Login</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="settings-menu" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" id="drop4" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>

     <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="form-group row">
                     <p id="pFooter" class="pull-left">Designed By Example, Inc.</p>
                     <p class="pull-right"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ReleaseNotes")">1.0.0.0</a></p>
                   </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/MyBundle")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The _UserLayout page

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "List";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar fa fa-user fa-3x">tester</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-brand" id="editUser">Edit</button>
            <button class="navbar-brand" id="addUser">Add User</button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li id="settings-menu" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="drop4" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
@Scripts.Render("~/MyBundle")
```

This page is supposed to use the _UserLayout page. However, I had to add the `@Scripts.Render("~/MyBundle")` to the page.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>User View</h2>

@Scripts.Render("~/MyBundle")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#editUser').on('click', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Why did I have to add `@Scripts.Render("~/MyBundle")` to the file even though it has the layout? Is there something that I could have done to make sure that the script references render properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include ~/MyBundle multiple times and this is causing problems.
Also you should use the Scripts section to render scripts in your views not like you did. Try using the following code:

For the layout - make bundles for all of the jquery and bootstrap scripts:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

And then in your view you can call your bundle like that:

```
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyBundle")
}
```

Your bundles should look like something like this:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"));
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                                                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                                                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-switch.min.js"));
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyBundle").Include("~/Scripts/yourscript.js"));
```

Also just a note about "bootstrap-switch.min.js" - bundles minifies the js files on publish so this won't work with the already minified file. Try to use the full version of this bootstrap component and include it in a bundle like i showed you above.